# React Native Rendering with SetInterval Issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, loops, react-native

I've just stumbled upon a performance issue with my app. I'm trying to make a game loop, with a `setInterval()` function and re-rendering my game constantly with `this.forceUpdate()`. I've also tried using `this.setState()` to re-render but they all feel the same. Now, in my gameloop, I'm constantly updating the y position of a blue square (View). It move's but it's a bit laggy.

I set the interval of the `setInterval()` function to 1000/60 to simulate 60FPS, but in my app, it feels like 20. I've also tried setting the interval to 1, and it's smooth, but it stutters a lot. I get tiny lag spikes that are very disorientating.

I don't think `this.forceUpdate()` or `this.setState()` is right in my scenario.

Is there another way I could do this to make the performance better?

**UPDATE:** I have used the `requestAnimationFrame()` function as well but it still stutters on re-render. Is there an alternative to `this.forceUpdate()` or `this.setState()`? And how would I delay the `requestAnimationFrame()` loop so it goes off at 60FPS?

Thanks for reading and I hope we find a solution.

Comment: This is what requestAnimationFrame is for. See https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/timers

Comment: @estus I forgot to mention, i have used requestAnimationFrame as well, it's smoother but it still stutters a bit. Is there a way i can delay the requestAnimateFrame loop so it only updates to 60 FPS?

Comment: I'd avoid using `setInterval` all together as you run the risk of multiple game loop iterations spawning if a prior iteration does not complete within the `1000/60`

Comment: I think it is caused by your render function.It's too Heavy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone wants to know, you really shouldn't be doing game code within react-native's state. Instead, write your game code outside of react-native. Example, react-native-canvas can graphically draw things without state!

Answer (score 4):

If you're adamant that `requestAnimationFrame` is not a good fit for your app/game loop, I would suggest using `setTimeout` over `setInterval`. The reason is, if a loop iteration takes longer than `16ms` (1000/60) to execute, then you'll get iteration overlap - another iteration will start, even if the prior hasn't completed. Over time, this will cause real problems and can be a cause of stuttering.

As an alternative, try the following (pseudo code):

```
doLoopIteration = () => {

    this.setState({ /* your mutation */ }, 
    () => { // This callback is fired after a component render caused by setState

        // Sechule next loop iteration in ~16ms. This approach protects
        // against the overlap issue mentioned above
        setTimeout(() => this.doLoopIteration(), 1000 / 60);
    })        
}

// Start the iteration
doLoopIteration()
```

For more on the setState callback, [see this documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate). Also, see [this documentation for details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval#Ensure_that_execution_duration_is_shorter_than_interval_frequency) on the overlap problem that `setInterval` based loops are sensitive to. Hope that helps!

Comment: Hey thanks for your suggestion, when i get the chance i will try your alternative and ill be sure to update you on whats happening. Thanks!

Comment: @ColeMangio hey you're welcome - yep, let me know how you get on and/or if you need any more help :-)

Comment: Hey, i've managed to implement your exact code, and it still isn't so good performance wise, BUT the setTimeout is a good though for delaying my loop! So, i've managed to make sort of a "Frankenstein" idea of forcing the update which calls the componentDidUpdate function, added a setTimeout to a requestAnimationFrame back to the loop. So, it's performance is much much better though. There is less stuttering. So i thank you for suggesting the setTimeout function. Also. i'm not sure if there is but is there some sort of other way of re-rendering the app?

Comment: Hi @ColeMangio, my understanding is `setState()` and `forceState()` are the only methods available to trigger the current component to re-render. How complex is the component you're trying to render? Perhaps you can simplify it to speed up rendering? Perhaps you could study https://github.com/FormidableLabs/react-game-kit to see how the game loop is optimised in that react game library

Comment: Hey! Yep i've actually managed to actually look at to game engines. The react-native-game-engine and the react-game-kit and i've looked at their gameloops, it they used the requestAnimationFrame(); function and subscribers? and for each subscriber in the subscribers array, it calls a callback? Like literally calls callback.call(); I'm not too sure what subscribers really are...

Answer (score 0):

Okay i think i've managed to make a frankenstein code from your guys's suggestions.
Here it is.

```
  componentDidUpdate() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      requestAnimationFrame(this.loop);
    }, 1000/60);
  }

  loop = () => {
    this.forceUpdate();
  }
```

I've noticed that the performance was actually better then all other methods i've tried. I think it's the setInterval/forceUpdate thats too heavy. Is there another method of re-rendering my app/game? Perhaps bypassing re-render functions?